# How to customize the Action button text in the soft keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am developing an android app. In my app there is a search option. I used `SetImeoptions` to change the text of the Action Button. But it shows the magnifying picture on the button. Actually I want to show text *search* on the button instead of the magnifier picture. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not. People are used to the meaning of the magnifier on Android. For sure, you have better features than this one to implement in your app, adhere to standards whenever you can, lower your coding effort and focus on important things.